# Daisies planted last year are not flowering

Tags: flowering

I planted several daisies last year.  They didn't flower then, but I assumed it was due to stress.  This year they appear quite lush, except that they're still not flowering.  Is there anything specific I should try?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daisies grow their flowers on stems, which come up later in the season. Those plants are healthy and should flower at the right time. You just have to be patient. That is how daisies look before they send up stems. If you wait until Summer, and the plants haven't sent up shoots, there is something wrong. For now, just water, weed, and wait.

Comment: Thanks, I was a little concerned because just about everything else has flowered.

Comment: Keep your fertilizer to a minimum and use an extended release fertilizer low in nitrogen.  The NPK, or nitrogen, phosphorus and potassium, the macro-nutrients are numbers that show the percentage of each nutrient in the fertilizer.  Keep the first number equal or lower to the P & the K.  If you use too much N, you'll get lots of luscious leaves and few flowers.  Be careful with fertilizer, it IS NOT PLANT FOOD.  Plants make their own food and only need a little of these macro nutrients.  These plants bloom in summer, late summer so you have a while to wait...need more late-blooming perennials.